# How to pass dictionary using pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

The following code gives the error "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def get_data():
  data = {'name': 'Bill', 'age': 20}
  return data

def test_get_data(get_data):
  test_data = get_data
  assert test_data['name'] == 'Bill'
  assert test_data['age'] == 20

test_get_data(get_data)
```

Comment: How are you running your test? You shouldn't have to call your test function in your module. Also you could just return the dict and you don't need to reassign `get_data` to `test_data`

Comment: @NomadMonad thanks